# dat.GUI doesn't update when I change the object

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

## Description of the problem:

There are 2 variable:

```
controller1 = {i: 100};
controller2 = {i: 300};
```

and a `control` variable

```
control = controller1;
```

I attached dat.GUI to `control.i`.

```
gui = new dat.GUI();
controller = gui.add(control, "i");
controller.listen();
```

So it displays the value of `controller1.i` and when I change value in dat.GUI, it changes value of `controller1.i`.

After that, I run:

```
control = controller2;
```

When I change the value in `dat.GUI`, I want it to change `controller2.i`, but right now it changes `controller1.i`.

Here is the pen: http://codepen.io/kranzy/pen/QKzYAW

or Stack Snippets:

```js
controller1 = {i: 100};
controller2 = {i: 300};
control = controller1;
click.addEventListener("click", function() {
  control = control == controller1 ? controller2:controller1;
});
gui = new dat.GUI();
controller = gui.add(control, "i");
controller.listen();
setInterval(function (){
  current.textContent = JSON.stringify(control);
  x.textContent = JSON.stringify(controller1);
  y.textContent = JSON.stringify(controller2);
},1000/24)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<h1>Controller 1: <code id="x"></code></h1>
<h1>Controller 2: <code id="y"></code></h1>
<button id="click"><h1>Change controller</h1></button>
<h1>Value of current controller: <code id="current"></code></h1>
```

> **The only way I can see is deleting the controller and init it again everytime I change `control` variable, but I want to know another way.**
>   That way is suggested here: [Refreshing dat.gui variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341872/refreshing-dat-gui-variable/40348161#40348161) (not really the same as my question, but related).
>   If you don't know anything about `dat.GUI`, you can take the tour [here](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) and see if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stupid... It's as easy as hell:

```
click.addEventListener("click", function() {
  control = control == controller1 ? controller2:controller1;
  controller.object = control;
  // change the internal reference in dat.GUI
});
```

I found that way after inspecting the `dat.GUI` object.

Test case: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBvvmV

Comment: Why did I get your bounty? Can you tack it back? My answer does not solve your problem.

Comment: @SanDroid read my comment. If I don't give you bounty, bounty will go to trash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by calling `controller = gui.add(control, "i")` you're passing the reference of the `control` object (current `controller1`) and dat.gui creates an internal copy of this reference. So if you overwrite the `control` inside the ClickEventListener dat.gui still holds the reference to `controller1` and all changes on the dat.gui tends `controller1`. I didn't find any possibility to reset the passed reference in dat.gui except to remove previously added controller and pass a new one.

Comment: I know that already; `dat.GUI` holds an internal reference. And what I want is find any possibility to reset the passed reference in dat.gui without removing previously added controller and pass a new one. But thank you for answering this question. There must be a person answering this question or bounty will go to the trash.