# Threejs - Remove GUI when loading new GUI

Tags: javascript, module, three.js

I have a module a.js where i have to right code for sean, camera, render etc. I have 2 module js file. cube.js and square.js  There is a dropdown on a.js. When i select cube then cube.js loaded with dat.gui and when i select squeare, square.js called with dat.gui. But issue is Previously loaded cube gui not removed.

a.js have code

```
import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
import { GUI } from '../jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js';
import { initGUI_cube, load_morph_cube, initializeMorph_cube } from '../js/cube.js';
import { initGUI_square, load_morph_square, initializeMorph_square } from '../js/square.js';
```

initalize some variable and then

```
   init(){
    ...
    }
change_shape(){
if(cube){
           if( initGUICalled == true ){
                 gui.removeFolder(upper);
                 gui.removeFolder(lower);
                initGUICalled = false ;
                }
initGUI_cube();
load_morph_cube();
}
if(square){
           if( initGUICalled == true ){
                 gui.removeFolder(upper);
                 gui.removeFolder(lower);
                initGUICalled = false ;
                }
initGUI_square();
load_morph_square();}
    }
```

cube.js code:

```
var gui = new GUI();
initGUI_cube(){ 
 var upper = gui.addFolder( 'Upper Measurement' );
 var lower = gui.addFolder( 'Lower Measurement' );
 }
load_morph_cube(){ obj, mtl loaded to get coordinates of cube. }
initializeMorph_cube(){}
```

Same process in square.js

Comment: Maybe this SO answer will be helpful somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348161/4045502

Comment: I checked it, but not get any idea. Sorry